# Obtaining Telephone Number from a Call at a Specific Moment in Time

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

New to Android development and I’d like to very quickly check if the user is in a call AND get the phone number of the person the user is in a call with.  In reviewing https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary, it appears quickly grabbing this phone number is not possible.  It appears the only time the number is available is with a PhoneStateListener and onCallStateChanged during an actual “state change” or using a BroadcastReceiver with state changes and grabbing EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER or related when a change occurs.  Am I missing anything?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not missing anything, that's the way to do it.